# hyperlink inside the rich text box

Tags: c#, richtextbox

sorry to create a new thread for this.

I have a rich text  box ,i use to pop up my xml data inside the Rich text box.

I have no idea how to hyper link some particular tag ,for me i need to hyperlink tag in the data.

[image: Hyperlink tag]

```
public void TEST(string message,string originalmessage)
    {
        txtOriginal.Text = originalmessage;
         richTextBox1.Text = message;
        this.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Here "Message" am passing xml as a string.

After apply the boby code here

```
public void TEST(string message,string originalmessage)
    {

    richTextBox1.Text = message;

    int startIndex = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("<Identifier>");
    int endIndex = startIndex + ("<Identifier>").Length - 3;
    richTextBox1.Select(startIndex, endIndex);
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;

    this.ShowDialog();
}
```

[image: Applied Boby Code]

Comment: Are you sure RTF supports this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one approach might be.

this in page load (for example )

```
richTextBox1.Text = "<TrainList><Header><Identifier>123457</Identifier></Header></TrainList>";
int startIndex = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("<Identifier>");
int endIndex = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("</Identifier>") + 13 - startIndex ;
richTextBox1.Select(startIndex, endIndex);
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
```

and then in click event

```
private void richTextBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (richTextBox1.SelectionColor == Color.Blue)
  {
     Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
  }
}
```

Comment: how is this line work ? richTextBox1.Text = "How are you " + link;

Comment: do i suppose to do it like richTextBox1.Text = message;
then int startIndex = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("<Identifier>");
please correct me if am wrong

Comment: In my code above link is just a string that equals to "Google"

Comment: First extract the value in between the <Identifier> tages i.e. if it was <Identifier>123456789</Identifier> your variable link in the above code will equal to 123456789. Then you will have  richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("123456789");

Comment: First of all i have to thank a lot to get me until so far.Look like everthin works but it change the color from <Identifier> to all the way down to last node.I just trying to color only <Identifier>123457</Identifier> only.Any help please

Comment: ok see the edited answer also can you please mark the answer as complete if it resolves your problem. Thanks.

Comment: My pleasure Usher. Glad I could help =o)